# How to create a branch of TFS and copy the details of one branch to another branch

Tags: c#

Scenario is i want to copy of the Main branch details into Feature or release branch if i will pass the path parameter in a console application

```
string uri ="http://portnumber0/tfs/DEv";

ConnectByCredentialsProvider connect = new ConnectByCredentialsProvider();
ICredentials iCred = new NetworkCredential(@"USERNAME", "PWD");
connect.GetCredentials(new Uri(uri), iCred);

TfsTeamProjectCollection tfsConnect =
           new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(uri), connect);
tfsConnect.EnsureAuthenticated();
VersionControlServer versionControl =
(VersionControlServer)tfsConnect.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));
string sourcePath = "$/project/Main";
string destinationPath = "$/project/Features";

versionControl.CreateBranchObject(new BranchProperties
                                 (new ItemIdentifier(sourcePath)));

int changesetId = versionControl.CreateBranch(
     sourcePath, destinationPath,
     VersionSpec.Latest);

Changeset changeset = versionControl.GetChangeset(changesetId);

changeset.Update();
```

Comment: And your question is..?

Comment: In this code only it will create a branch and i want to copy all the files which will be there in the Main branch and will go and copy in the Feature as it was there in Main